# How Do I Dynamically Set State Of Variable For Render Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For My Class We Are Making A Website With React And Neither Me Or my Group Can Figure Out How To Just Render A Function In A Variable State And Make It Dynamic

My Code Is As Follows:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      screen: this.home(),
      movies: []
    }
  }
  home = () =>{
      this.state.movies.map((movie)=>{
        return(
          <div>
            <Popular
            title={movie.title}
            rating={movie.vote_average}
            poster={movie.poster_path}
            desc={movie.overview}
            />
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  render(){
   return(
       <div>{this.state.screen}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I Run This The Error Reads

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'movies' of undefined
```

You Can Assume That The Variable in State Movies Is Filled With An Array Of Movies Set By An API

Edit: The End Result I'm Attempting To Achieve Is To Return A Variable Or State Which Can Hold A Function Which Would Be The Different Screens/Pages To Be Rendered

Answer (score 1):

If your `movies` array filled with data from any API call, then you can directly use that array to render the data,

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }
  }

  render(){
   return(
       <div>
       {
        this.state.movies.map((movie)=>{
          return(
            <div>
            <Popular
            title={movie.title}
            rating={movie.vote_average}
            poster={movie.poster_path}
            desc={movie.overview}
            />
          </div>
        )
      })
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thats what i originally had before refactoring but that is not dynamic i need a variable that can hold and render that so that my return can look something like 

```return {someVariable}```

which could then hold screens like

```this.home()
this.favorites()
this.profile()```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause here is that `this.state` is not initialized when you're using it the `home()` invocation in the constructor.

Either way, you're not supposed to store rendered content within `state`.

Based on the comment, here's a refactoring, but I would recommend looking into an actual router like [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) instead.

```
const HomeView = ({ movies }) =>
  movies.map(movie => (
    <div>
      <Popular
        title={movie.title}
        rating={movie.vote_average}
        poster={movie.poster_path}
        desc={movie.overview}
      />
    </div>
  ));

const FavoritesView = ({ movies }) => <>something else...</>;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      view: "home",
    };
  }
  render() {
    let view = null;
    switch (this.state.view) {
      case "home":
        view = <HomeView movies={this.state.movies} />;
        break;
      case "favorites":
        view = <FavoritesView movies={this.state.movies} />;
        break;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState({ view: "home" })}>
          Home
        </a>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState({ view: "favorites" })}>
          Favorites
        </a>
        {view}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is not just displaying it , the problem is when i hit a button in 
```this.home()```
 i dont want to have to physically change or add
```return<div>{this.home()}</div>```
i want a variable that can store a function being rendered like 
```
this.set.state({screen: this.favorites()})
return {screen}````

Comment: That's not how things work in React. You will need to change that line, but let me augment my answer...